# Getting weird data through JDBC driver

Tags: sql-server, groovy, sourceforge

I am using sourceforge JDBC driver for MS SQL database to read data and then process it.

This is how data read looks like:

```
def calculateHashedMessages() {
log.info('CalculatedHashedMessages')
def hashedMessages = [:]
def digestCalculator = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")

db.eachRow("""
            select top 1000 phone, text, id
            from proxyTable
            where dlr_description is null
            and processed_at is null
            and hashed is null
            """) { row ->
  hashedMessages[row['id']] = calculateHashForRow(row, digestCalculator)
}

hashedMessages
}
```

And then phone and text are processed in following way:

```
def calculateHashForRow(row, digestCalculator) {
log.info('calculateHashForRow')
log.info("PHONE: ${row['phone']} || TEXT ${row['text']}")

def phone = row['phone']
def text = row['text']

def token = "${phone}_${text}"
log.info("${token}")
  digestCalculator.update(token.getBytes())
//(digestCalculator.digest()).toString()
new BigInteger(1, digestCalculator.digest()).toString(16).padLeft(40, '0')
```

}

But this doesn't work and by logging I found out that the following is forwarded to calculateHashForRow method:

**PHONE: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@27d3bfc1**

**TEXT: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@3ed22c54**

Can anyone tell me why this would be contained in *row['phone']* and *row['text']* instead of values that are inserted in database?

P.S. this code is not entirely written by me and it actually works on different machine (with same settings) so I am a bit confused why it wouldn't work here.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
log.info("PHONE: ${row['phone'].characterStream.text} || TEXT ${row['text'].characterStream.text}")
```